# How to configure output in NDJSON format with NLog

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nlog, ndjson

I am working on .NET Framework 4.5.2
NDJSON format I require :
Nlog config in xml format for ndjson format given below

```
{
    "timestamp": "[timestamp]",
    "level": "[level]",
    "severity": "[severity]",
    "requestId": "[requestId]",
    "httpMethod": "[httpMethod]",
    "requestUrl": "[requestUrl]",
    "message": "[message]",
    "stackTrace": "[stackTrace]"
}
```

In the above format the following place holders are showing as empty for

```
httpMethod,requestId,requestUrl:
requestId&quot;: &quot;${mdc:item=requestId}&quot;, 
&quot;httpMethod&quot;: &quot;${aspnet-request-method}&quot;, 
&quot;requestUrl&quot;: &quot;${aspnet-request-url}
```

I already tried an alternative approach to extract the MDC properties and ASP.NET request information directly in the custom layout renderer

Please suggest what method can be used

Comment: According to your description, do you want to convert the csproj file of your asp.net project into ndjson format? This seems impossible, even if you convert it to an xml file in ndjson format, asp.net cannot apply it

Answer (score 0):

The [NLog JsonLayout](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout) can be used to produce output in JSON-format:

```xml
<nlog>
   <targets>
       <target name="ndjson_console" xsi:type="console">
           <layout xsi:type="jsonlayout">
              <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=o}" />
              <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
              <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
              <attribute name="stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
           </layout>
       </target>
   </targets>
   <rules>
       <logger name="*" writeTo="ndjson_console" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

You can use [NLog Context](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context) for providing additional details, and if your are using [NLog.Web.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore) then [${aspnet}](https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers&search=package:nlog.web.aspnetcore)-LayoutRenderers are available:

```xml
<nlog>
   <targets>
       <target name="ndjson_console" xsi:type="console">
           <layout xsi:type="jsonlayout">
              <attribute name="timestamp" layout="${date:universalTime=true:format=o}" />
              <attribute name="level" layout="${level}"/>
              <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
              <attribute name="stackTrace" layout="${exception:format=tostring}" />
              <attribute name="requestId" layout="${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}" />
              <attribute name="httpMethod" layout="${aspnet-request-method}" />
              <attribute name="requestUrl" layout="${aspnet-request-url" />
           </layout>
       </target>
   </targets>
   <rules>
       <logger name="*" writeTo="ndjson_console" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

By default then NLog ConsoleTarget and NLog FileTarget will add newline-delimeter for each LogEvent. Thus automaticaly output in NDJSON format.